# Gulp task delay in initiating

Tags: gulp

I've just set up a new project and decided to use Gulp.js.
When I run a single task, i.e. > gulp scripts *(task to jshint and minify js)*, the task it's self runs super fast, about 50ms; however there's a 2-3 second delay before the task initiates. Is this normal for Gulp? I ask because I don't get this with Grunt. Is there some extra leg work involved in setting up the Gulp task before it initiates? and is there a way do reduce this delay?

For reference I'm Windows 7, Node 0.10.26, Gulp 3.6.1

Comment: Please post the relevant code. You may have forgotten to return the stream you're operating on, which would make the task complete immediately instead of waiting for the stream to end.

Comment: I use gulp a lot and this seems to happen always. I have a superfast PC but gulp has a few seconds (1-5s) delay before it starts.

Answer (score 0):

The only initial startup costs for most gulp tasks is reading file data from the disk.  If you're reading a lot of file data in, that could explain the delay.  Other than that, nothing specific to Gulp that should cause the delay (that wouldn't also be there with Grunt, etc..)